# ionic and odoo using angular5-odoo-jsonrpc

Tags: odoo, json-rpc

I create new mobile app by ionic and odoo using angular5-odoo-jsonrpc
I got this error when use odoo12 :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot read property 'cookies' of undefined

My app is worked fine by odoo10 and odoo 11 and if i enabale cross origin in browser it work by odoo 12 but in mobile it does not work.
How can resolve this problem?

Comment: add cors="*" in the Odoo url route and check.

Comment: you could set cookies field in Setting-App in your Odoo UI